# why i'm getting this error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee

Exactly I've getting this error, and the error line was following as:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'employee WHERE dep_id=29' at line 1

1.UserDao.java:

```
public void deleteUser(int dep_Id)
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("delete from employee where dep_id=?");
        ps.setInt(1, dep_Id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check `"delete from employee where dep_id=?"` for funny characters. You could also try putting the table name in backticks.

Comment: I didn't understand buddy, I'm trying to give the value in this method and 'delete from employee where dep_id=0'. but nothing has been changed...@ EJP

Comment: If you run the query directly in mysql what are you getting ?

Comment: What part of 'check ... for funny characters' don't you understand?

Comment: Nothing has been changed buddy, @  Koitoer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was because I did not mention the DEPT_ID in database. It's been fixed.